# Intuitionistic Disproof of Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, infinity, constructive-mathematics

For uni I'm studying intuitionism, and I came across the following disproof for the IVT:
[image]
[image]

The thing I'm trying to understand is why this disproof is not valid in classical mathematics. In my research on intuitionism I read about some properties regarding infinity cannot be used in intuitionistic proofs, and think it has to do with this problem, but I'm not sure. Could anyone maybe clarify if this is the case, and if not, what oyther reason is there for this disproof to not count classically? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Curious. Welcome, please place the relevant bits of your post in MathJax rather than images. I don’t follow “unfounded opinion”. Indeed, if such a $k_0$ exists, it can be found by e.g. computer search. If $k_0$ doesn’t exist then the definition is ill-defined. I leave it to others to comment on the (non)existence of $k_0$.

Comment: @FShrike this opinion is unfounded as such a sequence has not been found ,or at least not at the time when this book was written, so saying this sequence exists or does not exists is unfounded.

Comment: In classical mathematics, either $\beta >0, \beta < 0$ or $\beta=0$. In each case, you can point out exactly where the zero is. In intuitionistic mathematics (at least one flavour) it is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @Trebor What is not necessarily the case?

Comment: Also, it is incorrect to say that "the principle of excluded middle is **false**". It is neither provable nor disprovable.

Comment: Have you learned about real numbers the classical way? If not, you are probably at highschool level.

Comment: @Trebor, yes, I'm in my second years of a BSc Mathematics

Comment: You can probably search about "Brouwerian counterexample".

Comment: Thanks, can you post this as an answer to the question, then i can credit you and have the question be answered.

Comment: Intuitionism is self defeating if it disproves the intermediate value theorem, since that is one of the most intuitive theorems of real analysis.

Comment: @Michael maybe you should first read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionism

Comment: If I'm understanding this problem k0 could also be "the smallest number for which the Collatz Conjecture fails" or something? If so, you are correct in saying the sequence defines a number, but we don't know what that number is. There are plenty of math proofs that show a value exists but can't necessarily be computed. If you reject the Continuum Hypothesis, you can create an entire set of such numbers.

Comment: @barrycarter Yes, $k_0$ can be replaced by any integer who's existence and/or exact value is undecidable or unknown. In fact, undecidable ones give nicer counterexamples because they mathematically show how IVT gives new information, but the unknown ones are usually easier to understand as a concept. Also, I wonder how CH is relevant here?

Comment: An aside - $k_0$ likely exists because $\pi$ is likely absoultely normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not like the term "disproof", because it suggests that intuitionistic mathematics would say that the intermediate value theorem (IVT) is false, *which it does not*. What happens here is that we show that IVT would allow us to recover part of the law of excluded middle. In particular, it would decide the parity of $k_0$ (if it exists). What this means is that we cannot *prove* IVT in intuitionistc mathematics.

Remember, *everything* you prove in intuitionistic mathematics also holds in classical mathematics. This is because every logical step you take in intuitionistic mathematics is also classically valid. It is the other way around that does not work.

So from a classical point of view all that this "disproof" gives us is that there is some continuous function $f: [0, 3] \to \mathbb{R}$ that has a zero $x$ for which the exact value of $x$ is tied to the parity of $k_0$ (if it exists). However, classically if we assert the existence of such an $x$ we make no claims about being able to locate it.